# How to set maxlength of column name while export to dbf file

Tags: c#, dbf

I am exporting datatable to dbf file.
If I have big column name, dbf file can export till first 10 characters.

Why it is like that?

```
using (var dBaseConnection = new OleDbConnection(
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " +
    @" Data Source=C:\Users\RobertWray\Documents\dBase; " +
    @"Extended Properties=dBase IV"))
{
    dBaseConnection.Open();

    string createTableSyntax = 
        "Create Table Person " +
        "(Name char(50), CustomerReference char(50), Phone char(20))";
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(createTableSyntax, dBaseConnection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Is there any setting which I can do to export more length in column names.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

DBF files have a limit on column length, and that limit is `10`. If you abstract away all access to the files, you can do the mapping in a different layer (making the actual column names in the DBF just shortened IDs); if you simply write "SQL" directly, you're out of luck.

Why the limit is there? DBFs are *old*. Why are you using DBFs for anything today? Maybe there's a better embedded database for your usecase?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Once doubt is there any limit on the length of data I can export in dbf with type = varchar?

Comment: @user1336662 Yeah, the limit is 254 (ASCII/codepage) characters. If you need more, you have to use `memo`, which is a lot trickier.

Comment: "Why are you using DBFs for anything today?" E.g., it is part of shapefiles.